# Python: getting substring starting and ending between two given substrings

Tags: python, string

What would be the textbook way of accomplishing the following tasks:

I have a string s of the from `s_s * s_l * s_q * s_r * s_e`, where by `*` I mean the concatenation operator.

Given `s`, `s_l` and `s_r` I am interested in returning `s_q`, we may assume that `s_l` and `s_r` only occur once in `s`.

As an example: `s = "abcdefghij"`, `s_l = "cd"`, `s_r = "hi"` so `s_q = "efg"`.

Would a regex approach be appropriate in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [110]: s[s.find(s_l)+len(s_l): s.find(s_r)]
Out[110]: 'efg'
```

Comment: You might want to use `rfind` on `s_r` to take the first occurrence from the right

Comment: @bnjmn the OP assumes `s_r` occurs only once in `s` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string, since you know that `s_l` and `s_r` only occur once each:

```
s = "abcdefghij"
s_l = "cd"
s_r = "hi"

print s.split(s_l)[1].split(s_r)[0] # Returns efg
```

You don't need to use regular expressions, because `s_l` and `s_r` are static.  If you didn't know what `s_l` and `s_r` are going to be in advance, only that they match some pattern, then regular expressions might be helpful.